# Syncing outlook.com folder to Gmail

Tags: email

I currently have a live.com email and wish to switch over to gmail. So what I've done is add the live.com mail to gmail via POP3 (imap doesn't seem to be supported by outlook.com).

While my mail has transferred over, their folders are not. Is there any way I can transfer outlook.com folders to gmail labels?